# App crashing while selecting check box in extensible list view in android

Tags: android, arrays, listview, extensible

Hi i am using extensible list view in my fragment, here when i am clicking on check box in extensible list view, i want to get the values to Main activity in array format. But app is crashing whenever am clicking on `checkbox`.

**ExpandableListAdapter**

```
package com.example.limitscale.beautylog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.limitscale.beautylog.model.BookedInfo;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
ArrayList<BookedInfo> selectedarray = new ArrayList<BookedInfo>();
CheckBox check;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    String valamt[]  = childText.split(",");

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    final LinearLayout content=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    final TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    final TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aMount);
    check=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    txtListChild.setText(valamt[0]);
    price.setText("Rs" + valamt[1]);

    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                BookedInfo bookedInfo = new BookedInfo();
                String check = "1";
                bookedInfo.setServiceName(txtListChild.toString());
                bookedInfo.setmServicePrice(price.toString());
                bookedInfo.setmBrandQty(check);
                selectedarray.add(bookedInfo);
                ((MainActivity) _context).checked(selectedarray);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}}
```

**here is my logcat**

```
05-20 12:27:21.715  30353-30353/com.example.limitscale.beautylog E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.limitscale.beautylog, PID: 30353
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.limitscale.beautylog.MainActivity
        at com.example.limitscale.beautylog.ExpandableListAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(ExpandableListAdapter.java:73)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18491)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:873)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:689)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Actually same code worked perfectly when i tested it as separate project but when i merged into my main project app is crashing when am clicking on check box.

Comment: Need some help to fix it , thanks in advance

Comment: Why using `((MainActivity) _context).checked(selectedarray);` line?

Comment: Please tell me whats the problem in the line "((MainActivity) _context).checked(selectedarray);"

Comment: I need to pass the data to my main activity like which row is selected and its value

Comment: In same project am using exactly same method in list view there it is working fine but its showing error in when am using extensible list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating `ExpandableListAdapter` with an application context, that's why you can't cast it to an Activity (That's what your error says). You must have something like `new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),...);` somewhere. If you are doing this on `MainActivity`, you must change that line to `new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this,...);`

Answer (score 0):

Please Define you check box in getView

```
final CheckBox check=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

If you define it publicly than you get only last checkbox value

Comment: You said right. But he need the array of values. Give the proper solution if you know @Jack

Comment: I changed jack but it still shows error in the line  "((MainActivity) _context).checked(selectedarray);" , its getting error even am passing string value also.

Comment: @GaneshKrishnamoorthy I have solution but the main thig is that Siva Kumar had to try first . if you have any ans please post it

Comment: @SivaKumar Please check whether context is passed is from MainActivity or is there any other activity

Comment: Hi jack i tried what u said but still its not working , if you have any any solution means please share it.

Comment: @SivaKumar What was the purpose of ((MainActivity) _context).checked(selectedarray);

Comment: I need ti pass the array list values to main activity when we select the item inside extensible list view

Answer (score 0):

Do following some edition in code and let me know if it is working or not properly.

```
 public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, Activity activity) 
 {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.activity = activity;
 }
```

and in check change, below changes

```
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            BookedInfo bookedInfo = new BookedInfo();
            String check = "1";
            bookedInfo.setServiceName(txtListChild.toString());
            bookedInfo.setmServicePrice(price.toString());
            bookedInfo.setmBrandQty(check);
            selectedarray.add(bookedInfo);
            ((MainActivity) activity).checked(selectedarray);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No vicky its not working.. Still showing error in same line

Comment: Show me your checked method in MainActivity

Comment: public void checked(ArrayList<BookedInfo> mArrService) {
        ((Newappointments) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)).selectService(mArrService);
    }

Comment: I think you should get Adapter in MainActivity only, so declare your adapter in MainActivity then you can directly call any method of MainActivity and perform operation as per your requirement.

Comment: Actually ExpandableListAdapter belongs to fragment so am passsing value to its main activity and from main activity am passing values to method in fragment , Am using same method in my listview also ther it is working great but now its showing error.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to activity first :

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
```

and then use :

```
((MainActivity) activity).checked(selectedarray);
```